# I need a mod to undelete my posts that were deleted for too little content

Tags: support, undelete, content

I have added lots of content to all the places where I answered a batch of questions that were all basically the same. I would have marked these all as dupes, but that is apparently an admin action or something:

- [How do I vertically center the modal in an iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3545966/how-do-i-vertically-center-the-modal-in-an-iframe/8155350#8155350)
- [Have modal center of browser with css/jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5877010/have-modal-center-of-browser-with-css-jquery)
- [Horizontally and Vertically Center Modal Div IE Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632746/horizontally-and-vertically-center-modal-div-ie-issue/8176196#8176196)
- [javascript to overlay a modal popup that is center aligned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/569149/javascript-to-overlay-a-modal-popup-that-is-center-aligned)
- [Center a div in a horizontal scrolling site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093315/center-a-div-in-a-horizontal-scrolling-site/8176204#8176204)
- [Automatically reposition Jquery SimpleModal to center of page when modal div is resized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235397/automatically-reposition-jquery-simplemodal-to-center-of-page-when-modal-div-is)

Comment: Tisn't so. Even if you can't vote to close a question as a dupe, you can still flag it as such. Unless you can't even flag yet, but I think you're past that.

Comment: You haven't stated an actionable reason for undeleting the content.

Comment: **+1** for actually editing all your answers to address the deletion. **-1** for assuming they were all dupes and posting a blanket answer on all. (for example, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235397/automatically-reposition-jquery-simplemodal-to-center-of-page-when-modal-div-is) specifically asked for help with the SimpleModal jquery plugin).

Comment: No, you are wrong, all the questions boil down to the person asking how to maintain their modal or modal-like element at the true center of the parent or viewport in the most efficient and accurate way. Please actually read and understand before exposing these broad strokes with such a tone of absolute certainty.

Comment: I'm so freaking tired of popping out these cool snippets of code that eliminate all this JS hackery that people are doing and reduce things to a little CSS and HTML, and not being able to broadcast a CLEARLY better solution because of this site's stance on answers. This is asinine and completely pedantic.

Comment: "this question specifically asked for help with the SimpleModal jquery plugin" - NO, it asks how to keep it centered, this is a way to do that for all modals with just layout and CSS, please read deeper before passing judgements.

Comment: Perhaps you're right. It is possible that I simply do not have the mental capacity to appreciate the brilliance of your answer.

Comment: Sometimes people ask things like "How can I use this butter knife to cut down this tree?", this was the case in these modal questions. Instead of telling them to use a grinder to sharpen the butter knife, tape a live woodchuck to the tip, then proceed to use the unholy amalgamation of steel and beast to attempt tree removal, I told them to grab a chainsaw instead (read: the appropriate tool for the job). Sure I could have said "add these 100 lines of JS to your existing 400", but I thought it would help *more* to say "you can get all this without the heft, just use these 50 lines of HTML/CSS"

Comment: Please don't just edit your question to obscure its content. If you want it deleted, we can do that. But editing like this doesn't really help anything.

Answer (score 11):

Your answers have been deleted, because all of them were exactely equal. Few of the answers did actually offer a relevant answer to the question.

According to the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion):

> Answers that ***do not fundamentally answer the question may be removed***. This includes answers that are … 
> ...
>
> - **exact duplicates of other answers**

Comment: Actually, when the posts were deleted, they were different but short and contained mainly a link to the same blog post. e.g. [1](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/8155328/revisions), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/8155384/revisions),  [3](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/8155350/revisions)

Comment: @ShawnChin I see. At deletion, the reason would fall in this category (same FAQ): `barely more than a link to an external site`. After editing, the reason is more leaning towards `exact duplicates of other answers`.

Comment: Agree. I'm not doubting the validity of the deletion. I'm just being pedantic about the reason for deletion as stated in your answer :p

Comment: I really take offense to this Rob: "Few of the answers did actually offer a relevant answer to the question."
My answer was totally on the money, show me where I'm wrong.

Comment: That's what I get for correcting what I was asked to, and mentioning that *I couldn't find the dup UI* in this thread right off the bat. Great usability folks, way to blame the person trying to populate the content, what a power trip, way to be.

Comment: Your answers showed how to visually center a specific element using pure CSS and HTML, which is correct for [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5877010/have-modal-center-of-browser-with-css-jquery). At the other questions, which mention a specific jQuery plugin or existing code, your answer does **not** answer the question. See my answer + the second comment in this comment chain for more details on the deletion reason.

Comment: It's not like I'm some StackOverflow whore here folks, I have like 450 rep or something, I just post when I find out something that can broadly help people. I don't care about blog traffic either (on a good day I get 300 visitors, because I don't care about being a "blog hero"). This is disheartening and makes me feel terrible about attempting contribution. If any of you actually code for the web, you would quickly realize these solutions can help you too. I really encourage you to check them out before just bashing people to smithereens.

Comment: @csuwldcat *Do not take it personally*. I do not have anything against you. Rather, I have given the reasons for the deletion (I did not delete them. Actually, I attempted to undelete one post, which failed because it's deleted by a moderator).

Answer (score 9):

For context, [your answers were originally deleted because they just consisted of identical short statements and links back to your blog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112709/how-to-not-get-suprised-to-learn-your-answers-got-deleted). You blasted out seven of these in the span of five minutes, which caused Bill to find that 13 of your 19 answers just pointed to your blog in this fashion. This clearly stepped over the line into being self-promotion, in addition to not being particularly helpful as standalone answers, and the answers were deleted.

In [his answer to your Meta question about this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/112716/135615), Bill provided suggestions on how to flesh out your answers so that they can be restored. You did so for [one of your answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3892864/19679), and Bill restored it. If you feel that you've improved the others, flag them as Other and write a detailed reason why you believe they should be undeleted. You don't need to come to Meta with this in most cases.

However, as pointed out in the question ["Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104227/is-it-acceptable-to-add-a-duplicate-answer-to-several-questions) merely editing these into duplicate answers is frowned upon for the reasons discussed in the answers there.

If you feel that the questions are true duplicates of one another, edit one of your answers to address the canonical question and flag the others (since you can't vote to close yet) as duplicates of that canonical one. However, from the comments of others here, it sounds like they are not true duplicates. In that case, tailor an answer to the specifics of each question rather than copying and pasting the same answer to each.

As a comment, your previous Meta question was severely downvoted because of your unprofessional attitude and language. Continuing to act in this way

> "Great usability folks, way to blame the person trying to populate the
>   content, what a power trip, way to be."

is not going to win people over to your cause.

Comment: I was cordial when *asking* my question, fixed my answers & openly admitted I couldn't find dupe UI. I got angry after folks insinuated I was spamming w/ irrelevant answers --> "Few of the answers did actually offer a relevant answer to the question." False, in fact one such answer that had been yanked (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2635814/javascript-capturing-load-event-on-link/5371426#5371426) was already up-voted 2x past the old answer. As far as the modal questions, jQuery SimpleModal is *not able* do what they want w/o *tons of hackish JS*, my solution can do it using only HTML/CSS.